# Filtering for newly modified files not returning new files

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm new to the Google Drive API. I have written a script in python which searches a Google Drive shared folder for files modified after a certain date. It works fine when I am the user who has uploaded the file to the Google Drive folder - but when a different user uploads a file, the file is not found despite having a modified date which should answer the search criteria. Wondering if this is some sort of permissions/scoping issue - all the users have full write/edit permissions on the folder within Google Drive

some of the code I'm using is:

```
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
page_token = None

query_filter = 'modifiedTime>' + my_timestamp
  while True:
        response = DRIVE.files().list(supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                      spaces='drive',
                                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name,modifiedTime)',
                                      pageToken=page_token,
                                      q=query_filter
                                      ).execute()
```

Thanks

Comment: Your scope seems to be right (maybe even too powerful).Are you sure you have set your permissions right? How are you authenticating? Is this a service account?

Comment: yeah this is a service account. authenticating with oauth (using client_id.json). They main issue here is that another user in the organization using GSuite uploads the file to the shared Google Drive but the Drive API code is not identifying the new file when it's run using the service account credentials. If I then go into the drive and make any change to the file (even just a rename), that modifies that file and then it is picked up by the Drive API....

Comment: Could you try to find the ID of the file and get it through [the API method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)? To make sure that the Service account does indeed has access to the file. Maybe is something about the construction of the list request?